# Explanation for SQL that finds difference in times between current and previous rows

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL, and while I've learned how to do the basics, I'm still not familiar with some of the more complex functions.  I recently discovered this snippet of code from a different question on here that does *exactly* what I need (finding the difference in times between the current and previous rows), but I don't understand exactly how it works.  I hate just blindly copying-and-pasting, and I might have to adapt this for something in the future.  Anybody willing to explain how this query is doing what it's doing (with emphasis on the SELECT FROM JOIN ON business at the bottom)?

```
WITH    rows AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UpdateTime) AS rn
        FROM    myTable
        )
SELECT  DATEDIFF(second, mc.UpdateTime, mp.UpdateTime)
FROM    rows mc
JOIN    rows mp
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UpdateTime) AS rn
FROM    myTable
```

means select all columns from `myTable`, and add column `rn` which will contain row number and all rows must be sorted by `UpdateTime` column.

Now, basically,

```
FROM    rows mc
JOIN    rows mp
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
```

means take `rows` with alias `mc` (m current) and join it with `rows` (same rowset) with alias `mp` (m previous) where `mc.rn` equals to `mp.rn - 1`.

The rest is obvious I guess?

Comment: I think I've got the hang of the WITH block, but I think the syntax of the second part is confusing me.  It looks out of order, almost, like it's referencing things before they've happened.  It looks like "rows" is referring to the results of the SELECT, but the select is using variables that are defined by using "rows."  I read somewhere that ON is used when you're performing operations on things that haven't been defined yet, but it didn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Comment: @NickGlowsinDark you are confused with declarative nature of SQL, compared to imperative nature of most programming languages. The command is a whole thing, and doesn't represent any particular sequence of commands.

Answer (score 0):

The important part is actually the `WITH` block, which extends the existing table information with a new column that just numbers the rows continuously.

The `JOIN` in the `SELECT` statement makes sure that *only* row X and X-1 are compared. For each row in `rows` SQL Server takes also the previous row and adds the timestamp difference in seconds to the result set.